# Siddhi plugin to interface with sqlite on Android

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am trying to implement Siddhi on the Android platform and was looking or a plugin to perform database operations with the native sqlite database. Is there any documentation on writing an extension to perform store operations with sqlite or a pre-built plugin to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use siddhi-store-rdbms extension to connect to the sqlite database.

Add the siddhi-store-rdbms dependency to the build.gradle file of your project.

```
implementation('org.wso2.extension.siddhi.store.rdbms:siddhi-store-rdbms:4.0.4') {
   transitive = false
}
```

Please refer to the following documentations for more information.

[1] Siddhi Android Platform : 
https://wso2.github.io/siddhi-android-platform/documentation/siddhi-android-platform-quickstart/

[2] Siddhi-store-rdbms : 
https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-store-rdbms/

Comment: How to make it? I use @Store(type="rdbms")  annotation but it is wrong when creat siddhi application. Thank you.